# Xamarin Forms App on iOS device crash "Application Settings exception" "Unable to store key" "got error: -34018"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, aws-sdk

Upon integration of AWS Mobile Analytics, my app constantly crashes with the following exception

```
System.Exception: Application Settings exception, Unable to store key APP_ID_KEY, got error: -34018
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the SDK was trying to write something to the `iOS Keychain`.

Hence, upon performing following steps, access to `Keychain` was enabled and crash fixed.

- Add `Entitlements.plist` file to project --> Click the checkbox `Enable Keychain Access Groups` to enable access to `Keychain`
- Save "Entitlements.plist" file
- Add "Entitlements.plist" file in `Project Options` --> `Build` --> `iOS Bundle Signing` --> `Custom Entitlements`